# Laravel 5.3 Roles And Permissions package error after upgrade

Tags: laravel, laravel-upgrade

I'm using this package [enter link description here](https://github.com/romanbican/roles) Roles And Permissions For Laravel 5. This package was working fine on Laravel 5.2 but when I upgraded to laravel 5.3 I started to get this error on many APIs `"Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"` Has anyone an Idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Clear your config `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Thanks. I did it but still the same error

Comment: Your current database is empty?

Comment: Not really, it is fine. when i downgrade laravel to 5.2 everything works fine

Comment: This package is abandoned and only supports Laravel up to version 5.1